# using jqlite to target nested directive element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that has a template something like:

```
<div class="some-class">
    <div class="some-inner-class">
        <div class="class-to-target">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the directives link function I would like to assign 'class-to-target' to a variable and then use addClass() and removeClass(). Can anyone recommend a clean way to achieve this?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated
C

Comment: I guess, jqlite doesn't allow to fetch element by class, You should use other approaches to get it e.g. angular.element(element.querySelector('.classname')) or something similar. After that you will be able to add/remove classes to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine with the ng-class variable.  You won't even need to use addClass() or removeClass(), you can simply manipulate the variables from within your linking function.  Here is an example usage:

```
<div ng-class={classToTarget: applyClass}>
```

Then inside your linking function you simply set applyClass to true|false based on whether you want the class applied to the div or not.  classToTarget should be set to the name of the class you want to apply to the div.

The ng-class documentation has some really good examples covering this exact scenario.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass for more information.